# Issue with defining inputSpec of openapi generator gradle plugin on Windows

Tags: windows, gradle, openapi-generator

In a gradle project on a Windows machine, I'd like to generate Java code from an openapi spec. However, I can't figure out how to specify the `inputSpec` parameter. For simplicity I describe the validate task since the issue occurrs there as well.

```
plugins {
    ...
    id "org.openapi.generator" version "6.2.1"
    ...
}

openApiValidate {
    inputSpec = "src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml"
}
```

leads to `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml on the classpath`

Expecting that I could have mispelled the path, I tried to include a typo intentionally

```
inputSpec = "src/main/resources/api/openapi.WRONG"
```

But this leads to a different exception

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':publisher-service:openApiValidate' (type 'ValidateTask').
> File 'C:\dev\myProject\src\main\resources\api\openapi.WRONG' specified for property 'inputSpec' does not exist.
```

If using

```
inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml"
```

instead, it says `java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: C:\dev\myProject/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml`

Next trial with an absolute path:

```
inputSpec = "/c/dev/myProject/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml"
```

Again, it fails with something different:

```
> File 'C:\dev\myProject\c\dev\myProject\src\main\resources\api\openapi.yaml' specified for property 'inputSpec' does not exist.
```

Notice that some path parts are duplicated there.

I tried running gradle (gradlew to be precise) in a git bash and from within Intellij with no difference.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to version `6.2.1` of the `org.openapi.generator` Gradle plugin. I've filed a bug report at gitlab for this:

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/14075

--Edit
I finally also found a way to set the path with `6.2.1`, this way:

```
inputSpec.set((new File("${projectDir}/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yml")).toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `inputSpec = file("blah/blah/blah.yaml").path`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Maven. The "\" symbol creates the problem in the path.

my workaround (until the library get fixed) was to create a property in my pom:

`<input.spec.original>${basedir}/src/main/resources/api/openapi.yaml<input.spec.original>`

then I replace all the "\" symbols to "/" using a maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.build-helper.version}</version>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                <id>regex-property</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>regex-property</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <name>project.apis.folder</name>
                  <value>${project.apis.folder.original}</value>
                  <regex>\\</regex>
                  <replacement>/</replacement>
                  <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

And finally i pass the value of the property named "project.apis.folder" as input for the OpenApi generator.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.0</version>
    ...
    <configuration>
         <inputSpec>${project.apis.folder}</inputSpec>
         ...
    </configuration>
...
</plugin>
```

I hope this workaround can help maven users

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround is to set the path as a relative path, without the `project.baseDir` variable, as follows:

Before:
`<inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>`

After: `<inputSpec>src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>`

Comment: I've tested the above on macOS and Windows, and I'm able to run the open api generator on both, using 3.1.0 spec.